# X11 problems when compiling openjdk 9 on centos 7

Tags: centos, java

I find problems when I started to compile openjdk for my first time.

Below is what I did

- hg clone http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/dev 9dev
- cd 9dev
- bash ./get_source.sh
- bash ./configure

Then, I got this error message

> configure: error: Could not find X11 libraries. You might be able to fix this by running 'sudo yum install libXtst-devel libXt-devel libXrender-devel libXi-devel'.

Then, I did what it told me to do.

After the installation, the same error still exists.

So I checked where the files lies on my machine

- rpm -qa | grep X11

  `libX11-1.6.3-3.el7.x86_64
  libX11-common-1.6.3-3.el7.noarch
  libX11-devel-1.6.3-3.el7.x86_64`
- rpm -ql libX11-1.6.3-3.el7.x86_64

  `/usr/lib64/libX11-xcb.so.1
  /usr/lib64/libX11-xcb.so.1.0.0
  /usr/lib64/libX11.so.6
  /usr/lib64/libX11.so.6.3.0`

so i tried the way of specifying the X11 path

- bash ./configure --x-libraries=/usr/lib64

Unfortunately, the same error still stays.

Can someone help me out of here, please?

thx

## update

Thank @omajid for directing me to the log file `config.log`, where I found that the configure is using the gcc in my linuxbrew installation.

> configure:56234: /data/alex/git/brew/bin/g++ -o conftest    conftest.cpp -lX11  >&5
>   /data/alex/git/brew/bin/ld: cannot find -lX11
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>   configure:56234: $? = 1

So after I exported my c compiler to the system one, the problem was fixed.

```bash
export CC=/usr/bin/gcc
export CXX=/usr/bin/g++
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the relevant packages needed at build time and the configure flags I use in [my spec file](http://copr-dist-git.fedorainfracloud.org/cgit/omajid/openjdk9/java-9-openjdk.git/tree/java-1.9.0-openjdk.spec?h=epel7&id=0ec355e1ab3ca10e640049f237988fba0f57127a) for building [unofficial OpenJDK 9 packages for Fedora/EPEL](https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/coprs/omajid/openjdk9/):

```
autoconf
automake
alsa-lib-devel
binutils
cups-devel
desktop-file-utils
fontconfig
freetype-devel
elfutils
giflib-devel
gcc-c++
gdb
gtk2-devel
lcms2-devel
libjpeg-devel
libpng-devel
libxslt
libX11-devel
libXi-devel
libXinerama-devel
libXt-devel
libXtst-devel
nss-devel
pkgconfig
xorg-x11-proto-devel
zip
java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel


bash ../configure \
--with-boot-jdk=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk/ \
--with-native-debug-symbols=internal \
--enable-unlimited-crypto \
--with-zlib=system \
--with-libjpeg=system \
--with-giflib=system \
--with-libpng=system \
--with-lcms=system \
--with-stdc++lib=dynamic \
--disable-javac-server \
--disable-warnings-as-errors
```

In any case, the error messages produce by configure are a best guess. You should take a look at config.log to see what test actually failed and what the error messages are. In this case, it looks like you are probably missing one of several X11 libraries. Possibly `libXinerama-devel`.

If this still doesn't fix your error, please paste the error messages from your autoconf log file (should be named config.log or configure.log, I forget).

Comment: Thank you for directing me to `config.log`. I've updated my question.